# Raspistill picture washed out or complete green in direct sunlight

Tags: camera, raspicam

I've create a script to take pictures periodically using my Raspberry Pi Zero W and a camera module.  The script works, but I find the exposure lacking.  In sunlight, the pictures are washed out or completely green.

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=$[$(cat /home/dacracot/pix/sequence) + 1]
SEQ=$(printf "%04d" $COUNTER)
echo $COUNTER > /home/dacracot/pix/sequence
raspistill -rot 90 -o /home/dacracot/pix/shots/shot-$SEQ.gif --encoding gif --nopreview --exposure sports --timeout 1
```

Is there a command line switch to handle extreme lighting situations beyond the --exposure?

Comment: I am also having this problem. --ev 1 --exposure auto helps a bit, but it is not the real cure. Better ideas?